# line not executing after async task in MAUI's page OnAppearing()

Tags: asynchronous, task, maui

I am making an app that will basically download pictures from my FTP server and displays them in a Gallery.

So on the Profile.xaml.cs page, I am just downloading pictures. The process is:

- GalleryImageButton background is red in the beginning
  -Load picture models from database
  -Check local files if pictures exist
  -If not, download missing ones.
  -after download or check, GalleryImageButton background change to green.

The problem is that when the Profile page loads, the picture models gets scrabbed from the database.

But the CheckAndDownloadMissingPictures task never runs.

And sometimes it runs, and the change the background of ImageButton to green does not run.

*pageCounter variable will be 0 when page is created, just so this task can be done only on the first load of the page*

**Profile.xaml.cs**

```cs
  protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        //Test case
        UsersData usersData = new UsersData();
          currentUser = await usersData.findUserByMailAsync("logme"); //just to test with test user

        await pictureController.assingUser(currentUser);
        //picture models scrab from database (picName,picDate...)
       if(pictureModels==null) pictureModels = await pictureController.ScrabPicturesFromDB(currentUser);
       //check download missing pics
        Task.Run(async ()=> await checkPicturesAsync());
      //  checkPicturesAsync();
      
    }
    private async Task checkPicturesAsync()
    {
        pageCounter++;
         if (pageCounter == 1)
          {
            /*  await pictureController.assingUser(currentUser);
              pictureModels = await pictureController.ScrabPicturesFromDB(currentUser);
             GalleryControl.BackgroundColor = Colors.Red;*/
           // Task.Run(async () => await pictureController.CheckAndDownloadMissingPictures(currentUser));
           await pictureController.CheckAndDownloadMissingPictures(currentUser);
            if (profilePic.Source != ImageSource.FromFile(local_image_folder + "/profile.jpg"))
                profilePic.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(local_image_folder + "/profile.jpg");
            GalleryControl.BackgroundColor = Colors.Green; //TODO FIX THE BUG (NOT LOADING)
            nameLbl.Text = "done";
          }
    }
```

**PicturesController**

```cs
  public async Task CheckAndDownloadMissingPictures(UserModel currentUser)
        {
            var localPics = await localPictures();
            //Checking profile pic
            if (!localPics.Contains(Path.Combine(localFolder, "profile.jpg").ToString()))
            {
                string link = createPictureFtpLink("profile");
                string localPath = Path.Combine(localFolder, "profile.jpg");
                await DownloadFile(link, ftpUsername, ftpPassword, localPath);
            }
            foreach (var pictureModel in pictureModels)
            {
                var picNameFromModel = Path.Combine(localFolder, pictureModel.picture_name + ".jpg");
                if (!localPics.Contains(picNameFromModel))
                {
                  string link=  createPictureFtpLink(pictureModel);
                    string localPath = Path.Combine(localFolder, pictureModel.picture_name + ".jpg");
                    await DownloadFile(link, ftpUsername, ftpPassword, localPath);
                }
            }
         }
```

Profile picture's loading works fine though.
I would appreciate your help1!

Before making the profile picture functionality, it was working fine and smooth actually.

The Profile page loads and checks for missing picture and in the end changes the background of GalleryImageButton to Green after checking and downloading, and when click on that ImageButton it indeed loads all pictures.

After I've added the profile picture functionality, this weird thing started to happen, i could not really understand where it is coming from.

Comment: Assuming `pageCounter` has expected value, if `CheckAndDownloadMissingPictures` doesn't run, its because `checkPicturesAsync` doesn't run. Using breakpoints, please verify if that is correct. (I assume commented out code isn't running.)

Comment: I had checked now using breakpoints and `checkPicturesAsync` did run and it looks like that `CheckAndDownloadMissingPictures` is also running because I have checked the app data in storage and it increased by 5mb (4 pictures) so i believe they have been downloaded. However, the turn color to Green line does not work even though its breakpoint was resolved as the previous ones. @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: I have double checked and everything is running until the `GalleryControl.BackgroundColor= Colors.green` the debugger just exits when reaching this line

Comment: You can only update the UI from the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing lengthy tasks in `OnAppearing` can be problematic. Maui internally has started the transition away from previous page, but is not yet able to display the current page.

In either case below, data loading should be done *on a background thread*.
BUT you must get back to MainThread to touch UI.

Either:

- Load the data *before* navigating to the page:

```cs
public class Profile ...
{
  public static async Task<Profile> CreateAndLoad(...)
  {
    var it = new Profile();
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
      it.Load(...);   // Your scraping and loading code. NO UI code.
    }
    return it;
}

// Usage where you navigate to page.
var profilePage = await Profile.CreateAndLoad();
somenavigationcommand(profilePage);
```

- OR: Let the page display, with a busy indicator, while loading the data. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75678301/199364).

IMPORTANT: `GalleryControl.BackgroundColor = ...` must be done on UI Thread.

That is, wrap with `Dispatcher.Dispatch`:

```cs
// Code that touches UI must be done on MainThread.
Dispatcher.Dispatch( () =>
{
    GalleryControl.BackgroundColor ...;
    ... additional code ...
});
```

For the code you have, this is the simplest fix.

Comment: I don't think that's the case because `ScrabPicturesFromDB` was existing before I added the profile picture functionality and it worked very fine. Is colors the image background in Red, scrabs pics, downoad and check, then turn it to Green.

Comment: I wrote the line about ScrabPictures before you gave updated comment about how far the code got. Removed now. Rest of answer still applies. In your case, you are doing the second approach I describe, using Task.Run from OnAppearing. You need to get back on MainThread to touch UI.

Comment: Yes actually this worked pretty smooth! Thanks mate!!